# Drawing an Ellipse in Openlayers 4 with interaction

Tags: openlayers, draw-interaction, ol-interaction

In OpenLayers 2, I could easily create a Control to draw an ellipse like this:

```
           new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(layer, OpenLayers.Handler.RegularPolygon, {
                handlerOptions: {
                    sides: 40,
                    irregular: true
                },

            });
```

In OpenLayers 4, as I assume, it must be done like this:

```
            new ol.interaction.Draw({
                source: source,
                type: 'Circle',
                geometryFunction: geometryFunctionThatCreatesEllipse
            });
```

Am I right and if yes, how does the `geometryFunctionThatCreatesEllipse` look like?

Comment: Working demo here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31647238/how-to-draw-an-ellipse-using-openlayers3/55441687#55441687